# How can i use the select method for Multiple properties with same property name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetFee(int? Class_Id)
{
    var list = Repository.FeeRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(i => i.Class_Id == Class_Id)
        .Select(x => new {x.tbl_SchoolProfile.Name, x.tbl_Classes.Name,  x.tbl_FeeHead.Name, x.Amount})
        .ToList();
    return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have problem to access the field of other tables  which is tbl_Classes , tbl_FeeHead is join with this fee table in FeeRepository.GetAll() i select all the data from tbl_fee it give compilation error **(An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with same name)** so how can i fix this error ?

Comment: Give the properties names - `.Select(x => new { Name1 = x.tbl_SchoolProfile.Name, Name2 = x.tbl_Classes.Name, ....})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the names you want in the anonymous object creation expression, e.g.

```
.Select(x => new {
    SchoolName = x.tbl_SchoolProfile.Name,
    ClassName = x.tbl_Classes.Name,
    FeeHeadName = x.tbl_FeeHead.Name,
    x.Amount
})
```

You can only leave the name out if the compiler will infer the right one from the value you're assigning, e.g.

```
new { Foo = x.Foo, Bar = y.Bar }
```

is equivalent to

```
new { x.Foo, y.Bar }
```

Comment: @FaisalShahab: I'm sorry, that isn't *nearly* enough information for me to help you. We have no idea how you're displaying the data, and "it shows undefined" is a very vague way of expressing the error. I suggest you ask a new question after doing appropriate research.